# Android: Passing a file to external app from "documents" folder as read-only

Tags: android, file, android-intent, readonly, android-fileprovider

My app opens some files in external apps for editing purpose. In some cases the external app can save the file, in other cases the app cannot save the file. The file is a normal file in the "documents" folder so it is not private and it is not read-only. But my app need to programmatically decide whether pass it as writable or read-only. When the file has to be writable for the external app I use an intent with Intent.ACTION_VIEW. What may I use in the read-only case? Maybe FileProvider, but it seems to be for private files.

Comment: If you know that external App takes read-only/Write mode as an input, then bind it using intend.

Comment: @Yup The external app is chosen by the user (by App chooser) according to the extension of the file or his/her preference.